# Need help in javascript to add class

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="username" onblur="class();" name="username">
</form>
<script>
    function class() {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username == "") {
            //Now here I want to add a class
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to add class when username value is not given. How can I do that?

Comment: `username == ""` is never true, because an element can’t be an empty string.

Comment: You mean to say `input` is empty?

Comment: Note: You can't use `class` as the name of a function in a function declaration (what you have above), because the name there must be an *Identifier*, and *Identifier* is "*IdentifierName* and not *ReservedWord*". `class` is a reserved word (one they actually started doing something with in ES2015).

Comment: Yes, when the username input is empty.

Comment: Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues with your code are that:

- You're using `class` where an *Identifier* is expected, but you can't use `class` as an identifier because it's a reserved word.
- You're getting the *element* for the `username` field, not its value.

It sounds like you want to add a class on the `blur` event, to the element that lost focus. If so, with minimum changes to your code, you:

1. Use a different name for the function, as `function class() { ... }` is invalid, `class` is a reserved word.
2. Pass `this` into your function in the `onblur`.
3. Declare an `elm` argument (whatever name you want) for your function.
4. Add the class to `elm.classList` (on modern browsers) or `element.className` (for maximum compatibility).

Example:

```js
function checkUserName(elm) {
  var username = elm.value; // Or ... this.value.trim();
  if (!username) {
    elm.className += " no-name";
  } else {
    elm.className = elm.className.replace(/\bno-name\b/, '');
  }
}
```

```css
.no-name {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="username" onblur="checkUserName(this);" name="username">
</form>
```

---

Having said that, I wouldn't use the old-fashioned `onxyz` attributes at all. Instead, I'd use modern event handling:

```js
document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  var username = this.value; // Or ... this.value.trim();
  if (!username) {
    this.className += " no-name";
  } else {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/\bno-name\b/, '');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.no-name {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="username" onblur="checkUserName(this);" name="username">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var username = document.getElementById('username').value

if (username == "") {
    document.getElementById('username').className += " someClass";
}
```